# foreach in controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have the following problem, I am working on Codeigniter and I am doing a small validation in the index of my controller this is the code:

```
function index()
    {
        $user = $this->session->userdata("id");
        $data = $this->customer_model->get_rol_user($user);

        foreach ($data as $row) {
          if ($row->Url === 'customer/index'){
               $this->load->view('guest/head');
               $this->load->view('guest/nav');
               $this->load->view('guest/section');
               $this->load->view('customer/customer_view');
            }
        }
        redirect(base_url());

    }
```

The query works fine, I have already checked, it returns me what I need is the following:

- **Url**
- product/index
- supplier/index
- customer/index

If in the result of my query I have the same value as my condition if, in this case if it is, I would have to load the view otherwise I redirected to the home of my application, I am failing in the foreach?

This is my model:

```
function get_rol_user($user){

    $query = $this->db-> query("SELECT p.Url
            FROM User AS u INNER JOIN rol AS r ON u.fk_rol = r.id_rol
            INNER JOIN rol_page AS n ON n.fk_rol = r.id_rol
            INNER JOIN page AS p ON n.fk_page = p.id_page
            WHERE u.id_user ='".$user."'");
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the returned error?

Comment: Apparently does not enter if, it always redirects me: base_url

Comment: try below answer if not works post your model's code.

Comment: Now I upload the code in my model

Comment: @max try edited answer.

Comment: may be the issue is with datatype ? check datatype of `$row->Url `

Comment: @HikmatSijapati This time if it enters the if, but I get the following error: Call to undefined method customer::redirection()

Comment: @OwaisAslam $row-> Url returns a string, which are the pages my user has access to for example returns me 'product / index', 'supplier / index', and if any of those results is the same as the one I have in my condition if , You have to let me in sight

Comment: could you post result of `vardump($data)`?

Comment: @HikmatSijapati is this: array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["Url"]=> string(18) "customer/index" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["Url"]=> string(20) "customer/guardar" } }

Comment: try like edited answer.in both ways..

Comment: i have edited according to your ways...hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Like this..

```
function index()
    {
        $user = $this->session->userdata("id");
        $data = $this->customer_model->get_rol_user($user);

        foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
          if ($row[$key]->Url === 'customer/index'){
               $this->load->view('guest/head');
               $this->load->view('guest/nav');
               $this->load->view('guest/section');
               $this->load->view('customer/customer_view');
            }
         }
            redirect(base_url());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag and redirect only if flag is set (in my example it it set as `false`):

```
$load_view = false;
foreach ($data as $row) {
  if ($row->Url === 'customer/index'){
       // flag tells us that `if` is executed
       $load_view = true;
       $this->load->view('guest/head');
       $this->load->view('guest/nav');
       $this->load->view('guest/section');
       $this->load->view('customer/customer_view');
  }
}

// no Url is found - do a redirect.
if (!$load_view) {
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Check values of `$row`, `$row->Url`?

Comment: Yes, I did the test with a 'echo'', and the result is what I need to compare with my condition if